# ReactJS error: Invariant violation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building an application with React JS and I am loving it so far. However, I'm getting an error and I'm having a hard time determining what I've done wrong. This is my error:

**Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: ImageList.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.**

This is my code:

```
// Box for user images
var ImageBox = React.createClass({
    closePopup: function(){
        React.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('imagesPopup'));
    },
    render: function(){
        return(
            <div className='imageBox popUp'>
                ImageBox
                <div className="popUpClose" onClick={this.closePopup}>X</div>
                <ImageList />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

// User image
var UserImage = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        <img className="thumb" src={this.props.url} />
    }
});

// User images list
var ImageList = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        <div className="imageList">
            <h1>IMAGES</h1>
        </div>
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a return statement.

```
var UserImage = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        <img className="thumb" src={this.props.url} />
    }
});
```

should be

```
var UserImage = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return <img className="thumb" src={this.props.url} />;
    }
});
```

and

```
var ImageList = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        <div className="imageList">
            <h1>IMAGES</h1>
        </div>
    }
});
```

should be

```
var ImageList = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div className="imageList">
                <h1>IMAGES</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```